# no restriction unique matches columns kind of error

Tags: sqlalchemy

i got this problem i know this could be more database related, i am uncertain. All model tables created fine except this one:

```
class OrderXPerformerxShow(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order_x_performers_x_show'
    order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('orders.id'), primary_key=True)
    performerXShow_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('performer_x_show.id'), primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Unicode(50))
    performer = relationship('PerformerXShow')
```

got this error:

> CREATE TABLE order_x_performers_x_show (
>       id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
>       created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
>       modified TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
>       order_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
>       "performerXShow_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
>       amount VARCHAR(50), 
>       PRIMARY KEY (id, order_id, "performerXShow_id"), 
>       FOREIGN KEY(order_id) REFERENCES orders (id), 
>       FOREIGN KEY("performerXShow_id") REFERENCES performer_x_show (id)
>   )
>   2014-01-25 20:03:57,801 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] {}
>   2014-01-25 20:03:57,874 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine][MainThread] ROLLBACK
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   blahblah....
>   sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «performer_x_show»

this are the ones related to ...

```
class PerformerXShow(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'performer_x_show'
    performer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('performers.id'), primary_key=True)
    show_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('shows.id'), primary_key=True)
    show = relationship('Show')
    price = Column(Numeric(8, 2), nullable=False)


class Order(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customers.id'), nullable=False)
    relationship('OrderXPerformerxShow')
```

mixing is this:

```
class MyMixin(object):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created = Column(DateTime())
    modified = Column(DateTime())

    __mapper_args__ = {'extension': BaseExtension()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error description is pretty verbose:

> "no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la
>   tabla referida «performer_x_show"

The problem is that in order for `OrderXPerformerxShow.performerXShow_id` to be a `ForeighKey`, it must refer to another table's `unique` column (either a PrimaryKey which is implicietely unique or a column which has a `unique` constraint on it).

The reason is that your `PrimaryKey` for the `performer_x_show` table is a multi-column one and consists of three columns:

- `performer_id`
- `show_id`
- `id`

**Solution**: make only `id` column a `primary key` (which is done by default, I assume), and create a `UniqueConstraint` for the other two columns:

```
class PerformerXShow(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'performer_x_show'
    performer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('performers.id'))
    show_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('shows.id'))
    show = relationship('Show')
    price = Column(Numeric(8, 2), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = ( UniqueConstraint('performer_id', 'show_id'), )
```